# pass apache httpd passphrase non-interactively to standard input

Tags: apache, passwords, command-prompt, passphrase, non-interactive

Starting apache httpd prompts for a passphrase string text like below

```
$ echo -n "mypassword" | /web/apps/perf/apache/2.4.46/https-model/bin/apachectl -k start
Apache/2.4.46 mod_ssl (Pass Phrase Dialog)
Some of your private key files are encrypted for security reasons.
In order to read them you have to provide the pass phrases.

Private key model.com:443:0 (/web/apps/perf/apache/2.4.46/https-model/ssl/model.key)
Enter pass phrase:
```

I tried the below options to pass the password non-intractively but none of them work.

1. `echo -n "mypassword" | /web/apps/perf/apache/2.4.46/https-model/bin/apachectl -k start`
2. `echo "mypassword" >> /web/apps/perf/apache/2.4.46/https-model/bin/apachectl -k start`
3. `/web/apps/perf/apache/2.4.46/https-model/bin/apachectl -k start << echo "mypassword"`
4. `/web/apps/perf/apache/2.4.46/https-model/bin/apachectl -k start << cat mypasswordfile` (where mypasswordfile is a file having the password.)

Can you please suggest?

Comment: The passphrase is there to protect the keys. If you store the passphrase on disk, in order to not enter it manually, you might as well store the keys unprotected.

Comment: The passphrase will be in ansible vault. What is the issue with that @OlafKock?